# How do i pass the hidden value from the html page to the component in angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass the price field as hidden to the component action using the following

````
<form #formValue1 = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(formValue1)" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="price" ngModel value="10">```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
````

But the value is not getting in the action in the component. The following are the content in the component file

```
 submit(formValue:any){
    var formData: any = new FormData();
    console.log("Form Submitted !",formValue.value);
 }
```

The price value is getting as null eventhough i set the value as 10. What may be the reason? is there any issues in setting the hidden field value?

Comment: You want to submit a "formValue1", but you never defined this value! The computer can't guess you want/need the value from the input

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try with `<input type="text">` before. It will make it easier to see what happens.

If you want to use `ngModel`, you must use the "banana in a box syntax" `[(ngModel)]="myVariable"` and you must bind it to a variable on TypeScript side :

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="price" [(ngModel)]="price" value="10">
```

**TypeScript**

```
price: number;
```

The problem is that the binding will not happen in the direction you think. The value `10` from HTML will not be reflected in the variable `price`.

Instead, the `undefined` value in the variable will be reflected in the HTML value. If you want to check, you can give a value of `10` on HTML side and a value of `20` on TypeScript side and see that the resulting value is `20`

As a result, the correct syntax is :

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="price" [(ngModel)]="price">
```

**TypeScript**

```
price = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'banana in a box' syntax on ngModel. try puting [(ngModel)] instead, then when you update the value in your html template, the variable attached to it will update as well.